# How to change.htaccess to allow access to multiple pages

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I took over a hosting account for a friend to host a second domain on his server.  All is good, except for the .htaccess file that was generated by whoever designed his first site.

The main site is: ra-pictures.com, hosted in the root folder /

The site I'm working on is posthumanmovie.com, which is hosted in the folder /posthuman

Here's the current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # route non-existant requests to single script
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,NS]

</IfModule>
```

When I try to go to posthumanmovie.com - I get a 404 not found error.

When I delete the .htaccess file, it works, but his other site ra-pictures.com has 404 errors on any page that isn't the index page.  Any ideas on how I can change the .htaccess file to allow access to all pages from both sites?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check against the hostname:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ra-pictures\.com$ [NC]
    # route non-existant requests to single script
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,NS]

</IfModule>
```